# i want to fetch the two different values from the 2 diffrent table of diffrent fields at the same time

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 table name as `p_order` and `p_customer`.

I have to fetch the values of `P_order_no` and `P_customer_name` from the respective fields

```
<?php
      $wherecat = "`p_order_status` = 'active'";
      $catsql =$general->GetRows('*' ,'p_order' ,$wherecat);
      $catRes = mysql_num_rows($catsql);
       <p><muted></muted><br/>
          <a href="#">customer name =</a>order no =<br/>
       </p>
 ?>
```

Comment: use MySQL **inner join**

Comment: your html should be placed outside your php tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `demo` query :-

```
select * from p_order inner join p_customer on 
p_order.customer_id=p_customer.id where p_order_status='active'
```

Comment: will u help me how i can write this in above code...means where i have to write this

Comment: what you use for connect for MySQL ?? @Ambuj

Comment: i just made one file named as cinfig and included in this file

Comment: this is working for me...but now i have to fetch all details from the p_order how i can do it.....

Comment: remove this **where p_order_status='active'**

Answer (score 0):

Try this MySQL query :-

```
select P_order_no, P_customer_name from p_customer 
inner join p_order on 
(P_customer_id = P_order_customer_id && p_order_status = 'active')
```

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving values from two table you have to use operation for that.For implementing join there is at least one common column is required.

```
select p_order.P_order_no, p_customer.P_customer_name from p_customer join p_order on  p_customer.customer_id = p_order.customer_id
```